# Can we escape verbatim string containing curly braces in Python?

Tags: python, escaping, rawstring, verbatim-string

I am using `pyodbc` library to connect my Python program to a SQL Server database. I want to construct **Connection String** using a verbatim string as under.

```
connection_string =  f"DRIVER={SQL SERVER};SERVER={server};Database={database};Trusted_Connection=yes;App={app}"
```

Escaping `{` by `\{` did not work.

Also making it both verbatim and raw by putting `fr` instead of `f` at the beginning of literal did not work.

Help please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `{{` and `}}` when you need a single curly brace. From [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#formatted-string-literals):

> The parts of the string outside curly braces are treated literally, except that any doubled curly braces `'{{'` or `'}}'` are replaced with the corresponding single curly brace. A single opening curly bracket `'{'` marks a replacement field, which starts with a Python expression.

Comment: If the driver is in a variable, you then need triple braces: `driver = 'whatever'; connection_string = f"DRIVER={{{driver}}} etc"`